# Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Tags: angular-cli, travis-ci, package-lock.json

I have `travis-ci` integrated with my GitHub account (https://github.com/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App).

When I updated `@angular/cli` version from 1.7.4 to 6.0.0-rc.3, the build started failing with an error:

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
    at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:37:19)
    at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:24:21)
    at TestCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:177:32)
    at TestCommand.<anonymous> (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:45:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:3:12)
    at TestCommand.initialize (/home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:44:16)
    at /home/travis/build/pradeep0601/Angular5-Router-App/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:100:23
```

package.json snippet to better understand the running environment:

```
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
```

Comment: I faced the same issue, and it was silly, this occurs when using terminal from visual studio code and and works when switching to windows default cli!

Answer (score 336, accepted):

I just had the same problem.

It's related to release v6.0.0-rc.2, https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases:

> New configuration format. The new file can be found at angular.json (but .angular.json is also accepted). Running ng update on a CLI 1.7 project will move you to the new configuration.

I needed to execute:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

This removed `.angular-cli.json` and created `angular.json`.

If this leads to your project using 1.7.4, install v6 locally:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@v6.0.0-rc.4
```

And try once again to update your project with:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow, You need to update webpack I guess

Comment: running `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4` results in error: `Collection "@schematics/angular/migrations/migration-collection.json" cannot be resolved.`. any way to fix it?

Comment: I am also getting ` Unknown option: '--extractCss'`

Comment: Make sure your npm and nodejs versions are up to date or you will likely  get a failure. `ng update @angular/cli` is all that is needed.

Comment: @user1932595 I had to upgrade `@schematics/angular` to the latest version to get past that error.

Comment: A short note on above.  The removing the .angula-cli.json did not happen for me until the second run of the ng update command.

Comment: I was getting the `Unknown option: '--extractCss'` error too - turned out the `package.json` contained it in the `scripts` section twice - deleting it solved the problem.

Answer (score 80):

I was getting the same error messages. It was a silly mistake on my end, I was not running `ng serve` in the directory where my Angular project is. Make sure you are in the correct directory (project directory) before running this command.

Comment: I did the same thing.  You create a directory to serve you project, and it creates another directory inside of that directory (slap myself)

Comment: i.e. ng new my-app, cd my-app (I saw this comment earlier but assumed it meant the top level one)

Answer (score 37):

With recent version, without `--migrate-only` I got the repo updated.

I did **ng update**

The Angular CLI configuration format has been changed, and your existing configuration can be updated automatically by running the following command:

```
ng update @angular/cli
            Updating karma configuration
            Updating configuration
            Removing old config file (.angular-cli.json)
            Writing config file (angular.json)
            Some configuration options have been changed, please make sure to update any npm scripts which you may have modified.
DELETE .angular-cli.json
CREATE angular.json (3684 bytes)
UPDATE karma.conf.js (1040 bytes)
UPDATE src/tsconfig.spec.json (322 bytes)
UPDATE package.json (1340 bytes)
UPDATE tslint.json (3140 bytes)
```

Comment: I get `Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.`

Comment: An unexpected error happened; package @angular/flex-layout has no version null.

Answer (score 21):

Well, I faced the same issue as soon as I updated my `angular cli` version.

Earlier I was using 1.7.4 and just now I upgraded it to `angular cli 6.0.8`.

**To update Angular Cli global:**

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

**To update Angular Cli dev:**

```
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install
```

**To fix audit issues after npm install:**

```
npm audit fix
```

**To fix the issue related to "angular.json":**

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

Answer (score 17):

Uninstall the old version of Angular cli, and install Angular CLI global:

Update Angular cli global package to the next version, "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0"

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@next
```

Generate a new project and default application by running the following command:

```
ng new my-project
cd my-project
ng serve
```

Comment: do not use cli@next, use cli@latest or you will get the beta versions.

Answer (score 11):

Try using the below command:

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4
```

It will perform the below

- Updating karma configuration
- Updating configuration
- Removing old config file (.angular-cli.json)
- Writing config file (angular.json)

Pls note that the above command should be run in the folder where you have file .`angular-cli.json` and it will be then replaced by `angular.json`.

Comment: I've run the command several times and the angular.json file never shows up. However, if i delete the angular-cli.json file, run the command, the angular-cli.json file is added back. what am i missing here?

Answer (score 9):

If you don't know the version ,current project has been made, you can omit `--from` command and type `--migrate-only`

> ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only

Answer (score 7):

If all sorts of updating commando's won't do it. Try deleting **package-lock.json**. And then run **npm install**. Did the trick for me after going through tons of update commando's.

Comment: Any reason not to take this approach as a default (dropping node_modules folder and package-lock.json), and just running npm install?

Answer (score 4):

It works for me:

**Delete folder** `node_modules`

**Run command:**  `npm install`

( If it does not work for the first time, repeat this 2 or 3 times, Its funny but it works for me. )

Comment: Why would repeating this process have a different effect than the first time?

Answer (score 3):

Check your folder structure where you are executing the command, you should run the command 'ng serve' where there should be a angular.json file in the structure.

angular.json file will be generated by default when we run the command

npm install -g '@angular/cli'
ng new Project_name
then cd project_folder
then, run ng serve. it worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Just **run** `ng update @angular/cli` in your console.
You might find some vulnerabilities after running the command (if using npm), but then just **run**`npm audit fix` in the console to fix them. This command will scan the project for any vulnerabilities and it will also fix compatibility issues by installing updates to these dependencies. If you do not wish to auto fix these vulnerabilities immediately, you can perform a **Dry Run:** by **running** `npm audit fix --dry-run -json` in the console. This will give you an idea of what the command `npm audit fix` will do, in the form of json in the console.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and what I did that works for me was:

1. Inside package.json file, update the Angular CLI version to my desired one:

   ```
   "devDependencies": { ...
     "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder, in order to clean the project before update the dependencies with:

   ```
   npm install

   ng update @angular/cli
   ```
3. Try to build again my project (the last and successful attempt)

   ```
   ng build --prod
   ```

Answer (score 2):

For me what worked was creating a **new** Angular project and just copied the angular.json file in the project that had a problem due to the fact that the angular.json file was ***missing***.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was because of global **@angular/cli** version and **@angular/compiler-cli** were different. Look into **package.json**.

```
...
"@angular/cli": "6.0.0-rc.3",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
...
```

And if they don’t match, update or downgrade one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced same issue and i just executed below command.

> ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.6.4

It simply delete `angular-cli.json` and create `angular.json`. You can find this in logs.

Once you start execution. You will be able to see below logs in your terminal.

```
        Updating karma configuration
        Updating configuration
        Removing old config file (.angular-cli.json)
        Writing config file (angular.json)
        Some configuration options have been changed, please make sure to update any                                     
        npm scripts which you may have modified.
        DELETE .angular-cli.json
        CREATE angular.json (3599 bytes)
        UPDATE karma.conf.js (962 bytes)
        UPDATE src/tsconfig.spec.json (324 bytes)
        UPDATE package.json (1405 bytes)
        UPDATE tsconfig.json (407 bytes)
        UPDATE tslint.json (3026 bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check your directory, you must run "ng serve " on the same directory where you have created the project.

So, first enter in your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link to migrate from Angular 5.2 to 6. 
https://update.angular.io/

Upgrading to version 8.9 worked for me. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I have an angular project folder inside a rails project folder, and I ran all the angular update commands in the rails parent folder rather than the actual angular folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error message inside a docker container. I resolved it adding:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src
```

to Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found that there was no package.json in my project (but only the package-lock.json). I then

1. restored the package.json from source control
2. uninstalled the global and local angular-cli versions (like the instruction says)
3. followed the standard upgrade procedure

..and all worked out fine. Took a while to figure it out, but that did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
~/Desktop $ ng serve
```

Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

```
at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:37:19)
at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/workspace-loader.js:24:21)
at ServeCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:180:32)
at ServeCommand.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:47:25)
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:7:71
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at __awaiter (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:3:12)
at ServeCommand.initialize (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js:46:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js:87:23)
```

> This is because I haven't choose the Angular project directory.

It should be like:

> ~/Desktop/angularproject $ ng serve

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to set my Ionic 4 app to run as a pwa. When I run the command:

```
ng add @angular/pwa
```

...got the error message. After some try and error I discovered that when my project was created the start command was wrong. I was using an Ionic 3 version:

```
ionic start myApp tabs --type=ionic-angular
```

And the correct is:

```
ionic start myApp tabs --type=angular
```

with no 'ionic-' in type. This solved the error.

Answer (score 0):

For people who have simply cloned a project and trying to run it, you need to run `npm install` first. I totally forgot to run this and was simply running `ng serve` before installing node modules.