# Error TS2339: Property 'JSON' does not exist on type 'Object'. ".map(resp => resp.JSON())" angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-service-worker

In my file contacts.service.ts. I have my own code

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable

export class contactsService{

constructor(public http: HttpClient){

}

getContact(){
     return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/chercherContacts? 
  mc=sa&page=2&size=6')
     .map(resp => resp.JSON());


 }
```

}

I have a problem in the function **getContact()** because **HttpClient** does not want map and i receive the message and I get the message: **Property 'JSON' does not exist on type 'Object'**

How can to modify this code when i forget the **.map** in this function

Give me the advice when i can to correct this code in my project and think of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular `HttpClient` 4.x+, it parses the JSON response into an object by default, you don't need to execute `json()` against the response as you did with version 2.x and lower. You can simply do:

```
getContact() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/chercherContacts?mc=sa&page=2&size=6');
}
```

You only need to specify a [responseType](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data) if it's not JSON:

```
getContact() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/chercherContacts?mc=sa&page=2&size=6', {responseType: 'text'});
}
```

Also, check out the 4.x docs regarding [Typechecking the response](https://v4.angular.io/guide/http#typechecking-the-response) where you can specify an interface to tell `HttpClient` what type the response will be. This is recommended and will provide typing support in the consuming components/services/etc:

```
SomeInterface {
 foo: number;
 bar: string;
}

getContact() {
  return this.http.get<SomeInterface>('http://localhost:8080/chercherContacts?mc=sa&page=2&size=6');
}
```

Here is a simple [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk3obz) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

In my application. I have a service in the directory **services** in this folder i have my first service when i put the **contact.service.ts** In this service i have

```
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable

export  class ContactsService {

constructor( public http: HttpClient){

}

getContacts(){
  return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/findPersons?mc=wa&page=1&size=6");
}

}
```

in my component **contact.component.ts** i want to receive this **url** whenever i write in this document this code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {ContactsService} from "../../services/contact.service";

@Component({
selector: 'app-contact',
templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

pageContacts: any;

constructor(public http: HttpClient, public contactService: ContactsService) { }

ngOnInit() {

this.contactService.getContacts().subscribe(data => {
  this.pageContacts = data;
}, err => {
  console.log("L'erreuR : "+err);
});

 }

}
```

But i have an error **ERROR in src/services/contact.service.ts(4,1): error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.**

the ligne(4,1) is in the ligne of **@Injectable** i don't know where is the problem

my problem is to cut this code

```
ngOnInit() {
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/findPersons?mc=wa&page=1&size=6')
  .subscribe(data =>{
    this.pageContacts = data;
  }, err => {
    console.log('ErreuR : '+err);
  });

}
```

in two. One of the service when i receive the url and the second for to write the data in the page web

And that's all

Answer (score 0):

the version of the angular will make a defuculty in my project 
i follow this page when i run my application

[Angular Injectable decorator - Expected 0 arguments but got 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307628/angular-injectable-decorator-expected-0-arguments-but-got-1)

thank you all my friend in this stackover :)