# error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression. Angular

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a problem in my project angular but i don't know where is the problem. I want to add a service in my project in that i define this service like that

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http} from "@angular/http";

@Injectable

export class ContactService{

constructor(public http: Http){

}
  getContacts(){
     return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/findPersons? 
      mc=wa&page=1&size=6").map(resp => resp.json());
}
}
```

in the console of my IDE i have this mistake **ERROR in src/contact.service/contacts.service.ts(4,1): error TS1238: Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression.**

And i have the same mistake

[image]

is there anyone who can help me and thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
@Injectable
```

to

```
@Injectable()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's for the version of the angular 4, 5 or 6 
I followed this pages for to update my version and will be run

[Angular Injectable decorator - Expected 0 arguments but got 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307628/angular-injectable-decorator-expected-0-arguments-but-got-1)

Thank you my Friend