# Angular Injectable Error: Expected 0 arguments but got 1

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I know this question already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307628/angular-injectable-decorator-expected-0-arguments-but-got-1), but I am unable to resolve my error.

I just started ionic project and using this [link](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-login-angular/) to use auth using angular.

Everything working file but when I used

`@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})`

I am getting error

`Typescript Error
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`

I follow every step mentioned in above link like:

1: `npm install npm@latest -g`

2: `npm install -g @angular/cli, npm install @angular/cli`

3: `ng update @angular/cli`

but when I use 4th step `ng update @angular/core` I am getting this  `Package "@ionic-native/splash-screen" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.5.11", would install "6.4.0").`

when i run `ng update rxjs` i am getting this `Package "@angular/http" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.5.0", would install "6.4.0").`

and when I update `http` using `ng update @angular/http`, i am again getting this `Package "@ionic-native/core" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.5.11", would install "6.4.0").`

So I am unable to upgrade `@angular/core`.

PS: I am totally new to ionic / angular, and I dont know whether I have issue in `core version` or anything else.

Note: I tried `ng update`, `ng update --all`, also tried to clean uninstall and re-install but nothing worked so far.

Versions:

`Ionic Framework: 3.9.3
Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.3
Angular Core: ^5.2.11
Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
Node: 10.15.3
OS Platform: Windows 7
Navigator Platform: Win32
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36`

Angular CLI: 7.3.8

Node: 10.15.3

OS: win32 x64

Angular: 5.2.11

... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http

... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

### Package                           Version

@angular-devkit/architect         0.13.8

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.0.35

@angular-devkit/core              7.3.8

@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.8

@angular/cli                      7.3.8

@angular/compiler-cli             7.2.12

@schematics/angular               7.3.8

@schematics/update                0.13.8

rxjs                              5.5.11

typescript                        2.6.2

webpack                           3.12.0

Comment: I've never used ionic. But you're using version 3.9.3, which depends on a version of ANgular that is older than the one you're trying to upgrade to. The current version of Ionic is 4.2.0. If you just started an ionic project, why did you start with an old version?

Comment: Reproduce the issue in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Looks like you are providing in either constructor or function some argument which is not expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but I think it seems like a dead lock situation. Can you manually update below versions of `angular` and `rxjs` and do

```
npm i
```

and then try to update `ionic`:

```
    "@angular/animations": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/common": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "7.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "7.1.4",     
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.6.1",
    "omni-slider": "1.2.1",
    "pikaday": "1.8.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
```

Comment: also, if you have any exp in ionic angular then plz check  this qoes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55613214/core-js15724-error-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-angular-ionic

Comment: @Vivek : sure, let me check