# core.js:15724 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am developing a ionic project using [this](https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-login-angular/) referral, but I stuck on error and can't find solution.

After reading some block, I think it's related to calling a function in loop but I can't find any such function.

Error:

```
 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:83)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:41)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:84)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
    at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  // { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './public/login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'register', loadChildren: './public/register/register.module#RegisterPageModule' },
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './members/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardPageModule' },
  { 
    path: 'members', 
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: './members/member-routing.module#MemberRoutingModule'
  },
  { path: 'check', loadChildren: './public/check/check.module#CheckPageModule' },
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: The reference is 26 min long video. And the code you have provided is just of module files. Can you create a git repo and share the url so that we can test it easily

Comment: Sure and I will post url here

Answer (score 0):

you may miss **import router module** in  **login module**, check it again.

Answer (score 0):

Add your AppComponent in routes like this.

```
const routes: Routes = [
     {
      path: '', component: AppComponent,
     }
];
```