# Expected 0 arguments but got 1 in ionic 3 provider injectalble issue

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular6

When I try to add api connection part in the ionic provider from Angular web app service it shows Expected 0 arguments but got 1 in here:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
```

While the same is working in the Angular web project.

Ionic3 provider looks like this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

const BASEURL = 'http://domain...';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthProvider {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  RegisterUser(body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${BASEURL}/register`, body);
  }

  LoginUser(body): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(`${BASEURL}/login`, body);
  }
}
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

change this :

(new in angular 6 wont work in ionic 3)

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
```

to this

```
@Injectable()
```

or 
**upgrade** to ionic 4

Comment: Will it work without provided In: 'root'? Because in Angular it was used.

Comment: @NewTechLover take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50307628/angular-injectable-decorator-expected-0-arguments-but-got-1

Comment: @NewTechLover ionic 3 does not officially support angular 6 https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/upgrading-to-angular-6/131121/5