# Hosting website in XAMPP failed

Tags: php, angularjs, xampp

I have a website which uses AngularJS 1.5.x as front end and PHP as back end. I want to host that on my local machine. I choose XAMPP to do that. I followed the procedure got from different sources but I cannot get that done.
I have done

> ng build --prod
>
> It's giving me error like Local workspace file ('angular.json') could
> not be found

I am stuck with this problem. I cannot go forward. I am new to AngularJS and PHP. Can some one help me out.

I have got the code from git hub. Just for practice I am trying to host this first. But I am unable to do that.

The folder structure is as [image: like these]

Comment: run `npm install`. It will download the necessary libraries required to run your angular application

Comment: yeah done that.... even running into the same problem. @Abhishek

Comment: does `ng serve` work?

Comment: If I run `npm install`. It's just adding package-lock.json file with code `{
  "lockfileVersion": 1
}` but know change in the error...

Comment: ng serve is also running into same problem.... @Abhishek

Comment: [Already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810580/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found) Check this link

Comment: Followed that getting new Error `This command can only be run inside of a CLI project` I have installed @angular/cli globally and give it a shot. Even ran into same problem. @Abhishek

Comment: Can you post the github link? I will run that code on my machine then it would make sense. I have same setup as yours.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/keithbox/AngularJS-CRUD-PHP) here is the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172669/discussion-between-abhishek-and-sravani).