# workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install, angular-cli-v6

I'm trying to run my angular application with `ng serve` but get this error:

```
Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.
    at WorkspaceLoader._getProjectWorkspaceFilePath (C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:38:19)
    at WorkspaceLoader.loadWorkspace (C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\workspace-loader.js:25:21)
    at ServeCommand._loadWorkspaceAndArchitect (C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:181:32)
    at ServeCommand.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:48:25)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:3:12)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:47:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js:83:23)
```

i followed the suggestions given on this question [Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810580/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found) - without any luck.

when i run ng -v on a global scope

```
 C:\Users\Roy>ng -v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.1.0-beta.2
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.7.0-beta.2
@angular-devkit/core         0.7.0-beta.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.0-beta.2
@schematics/angular          0.7.0-beta.2
@schematics/update           0.7.0-beta.2
rxjs                         6.2.0
typescript                   2.7.2
```

when i run it in the project folder :

```
ng -v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.1.0-beta.2
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.7.0-beta.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         0.7.0-beta.2 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.0-beta.2 (cli-only)
@angular/cdk                 5.2.4
@angular/cli                 <error>
@angular/material            5.2.4
@schematics/angular          0.7.0-beta.2 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.7.0-beta.2 (cli-only)
rxjs                         5.5.7
typescript                   2.4.2
```

when running npm install on the project folder i get this error :

```
npm install
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to http://172.23.4.20:4873/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Roy\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-11T09_24_47_695Z-debug.log
```

Comment: are you in the angular project? try running the same command after running this command 'npm cache clean -f`

Comment: yes, I'm in an angular project. I have tried running `npm cache clean -f` followed by npm install but still gets the same error

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue today. There were nothing wrong in my case, but just a silly mistake. I was running my command `ng serve` and other `angular cli` commands outside of my app directory(which contains the `node_modules`. So, after move to that directory using `cd m4moviesapp`, and then run `ng serve` everything was working as expected.

**Directory**

[image]

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I'm working in a git environment and someone pushed an npmrc file with settings that only allow downloading from our internal server, that's why every time I ran  `npm install` i got an error trying to download the angular-cli.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you have install angular in some directory and trying to use ng serve without creating your new project set-up
  Generating and serving an Angular project via a development server
ng new PROJECT-NAME
cd PROJECT-NAME
ng serve 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#generating-and-serving-an-angular-project-via-a-development-server

Answer (score -1):

I ran "npm install," my project got all of the modules and it ran.