# Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. But same code works in another computer

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am getting following error in one computer, but it works in another computer for the same source code

> Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found. Error: Local
>   workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found

***Not working computer***

[image]

***Working computer***

[image]

I tried following commands mentioned in this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810580/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found), but no luck

> ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.4 This removed
>   .angular-cli.json and created angular.json.
>
> If this leads to your project using 1.7.4, install v6 locally:
>
> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@v6.0.0-rc.4

***Not working computer ng version***

PS D:\Work\Source> ng -v
Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.8) is greater than your local
version (6.0.0-rc.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

```
 _                      _                 ____ _     ___
/ \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
```

/ △ \ | '_ \ / _`| | | | |/ _` | '**|   | |   | |    | |
  /**  \| | | | (| | |*| | | (*| | |      | |***| |*** | |
 /*/   __| |*|__, |__,*|*|__,*|*|       ____|_____|***|
                |***/

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0-rc.4
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.5.6
@angular-devkit/core         0.5.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.5.6 (cli-only)
@angular/cli                 6.0.0-rc.4
@ngtools/json-schema         1.2.0
@schematics/angular          0.5.6 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.5.6
rxjs                         5.5.10
typescript                   2.5.3
```

***Working computer ng -version***

```
PS V:\Jaison\Incomming\HISUI_Grid\HISUI\HISUI_04July2018\HISUI\src> ng -v
Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.8) is greater than your local
version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/

Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 8.9.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
```

Comment: I hope you are running ng serve in the directory where your Angular project is

Comment: yes off-course :) you can cross check the terminal command line path with the source tree path

Comment: yes, I did have an answer for you please check if that works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it’s probably because your global @angular/ cli, project @angular/cli version or @angular/compiler-cli doesn’t match.

Debugging this

> first of all run

```
ng -v
```

to check the global version of your angular, then compare the version with your angular project versions. if it matches with them or no.

If something doesn’t match, update or downgrade it. For example to downgrade project @angular/cli run

```
npm uninstall -D @angular/cli

npm install -D @angular/cli@5.2.0
```

To upgrade global run @angular/cli run

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: i have updated the question , please check ... what command i need to run

Comment: so as per the comment above , the angular CLI working version is 1.7.4 and non working version is 6.0.0-rc.4.. So i need to downgrate to 1.7.4???

Comment: no, you need to update angular CLI of your local system, by using npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 7):

Also, make sure you're in the folder where the angular.json file is located. That's what my issue turned out to be. Doh! I was in the parent folder in the cmd window and it didn't like that. Changing directory to the project folder fixed the issue for me. Sort of an "is it plugged in" solution, but thought I'd share it anyway.